# Python: Convert multiple YAML documents to JSON

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, yaml

I'm currently trying to put convert some YAML into JSON using python, and am having a hard time getting the JSON formatted properly.  My YAML file has multiple documents that look like this:

```
title: Windows Shell Spawning Suspicious Program
status: experimental
description: Detects a suspicious child process of a Windows shell
references:
    - https://mgreen27.github.io/posts/2018/04/02/DownloadCradle.html
author: Florian Roth
date: 20018/04/06
logsource:
    product: windows
    service: sysmon
detection:
    selection:
        EventID: 1
        ParentImage:
            - '*\mshta.exe'
            - '*\powershell.exe'
            - '*\cmd.exe'
            - '*\rundll32.exe'
            - '*\cscript.exe'
            - '*\wscript.exe'
            - '*\wmiprvse.exe'
        Image:
            - '*\schtasks.exe'
            - '*\nslookup.exe'
            - '*\certutil.exe'
            - '*\bitsadmin.exe'
            - '*\mshta.exe'
    condition: selection
fields:
    - CommandLine
    - ParentCommandLine
falsepositives:
    - Administrative scripts
level: medium
...
```

What I'm trying to do is for every document, pull the detection, fields, falsepositives, and level and put those into a JSON document as individual arrays.  My first attemp was pretty poor, and just lumped the groups from every document into lists:

```
data = {}
data['indicator'] = {}
data['indicator']['detection']=[]
data['indicator']['fields']=[]
data['indicator']['false positives']=[]
data['indicator']['level']=[]
with open(yaml_file, 'r') as yaml_in, open(json_file, 'a') as definition:
     loadyaml = yaml.safe_load_all(yaml_in)
     for item in loadyaml:
         for header, subsections in item.iteritems():
             if header == 'detection':
                 data['indicator']['detection'].append(subsections)
             elif header == 'fields':
                 data['indicator']['fields'].append(subsections)
             elif header == 'false positives':
                 data['indicator']['false positives'].append(subsections)
             elif header == 'level':
                 data['indicator']['level'].append(subsections)

     json.dump(data, definition, indent=4)
```

I'd like for each of my documents to be entered into my json doc as individual indicators, with their detection, fields, dalspositives, and levels all grouped together -- but my python abilities are failing me.

Any insight I could get on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the output you want by iterating over `.load_all()` and a much smaller program:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml
import json

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe')
ind = dict()
data = dict(indicator=ind)
for d in yaml.load_all(open('input.yaml')):
    for k in ('detection', 'fields', 'falsepositives', 'level'):
        ind.setdefault(k, []).append(d[k])

json.dump(data, sys.stdout, indent=2)
```

If you have a file `input.yaml`:

```
---
title: Windows Shell Spawning Suspicious Program
status: experimental
description: Detects a suspicious child process of a Windows shell
references:
    - https://mgreen27.github.io/posts/2018/04/02/DownloadCradle.html
author: Florian Roth
date: 20018/04/06
logsource:
    product: windows
    service: sysmon
detection:
    selection:
        EventID: 1
        ParentImage:
            - '*\mshta.exe'
            - '*\powershell.exe'
            - '*\cmd.exe'
            - '*\rundll32.exe'
            - '*\cscript.exe'
            - '*\wscript.exe'
            - '*\wmiprvse.exe'
        Image:
            - '*\schtasks.exe'
            - '*\nslookup.exe'
            - '*\certutil.exe'
            - '*\bitsadmin.exe'
            - '*\mshta.exe'
    condition: selection
fields:
    - CommandLine
    - ParentCommandLine
falsepositives:
    - Administrative scripts
level: medium
...
---
title: Bash starting just what is asked
status: stabel
description: No negative side effects
references:
    - https://nblue24.github.io/posts/2019/04/01/DownloadBed.html
author: Axel Roth
date: 2019/04/01
logsource:
    product: linux
    service: good
detection:
    selection:
        EventID: 42
        ParentImage:
            - '*/bash'
            - '*/ash'
        Image:
            - systemctl
            - init
    condition: selection
fields:
    - Shell
    - ParentShell
falsepositives:
    - root programs
level: high
...
```

Your output will be:

```
{
  "indicator": {
    "detection": [
      {
        "selection": {
          "EventID": 1,
          "ParentImage": [
            "*\\mshta.exe",
            "*\\powershell.exe",
            "*\\cmd.exe",
            "*\\rundll32.exe",
            "*\\cscript.exe",
            "*\\wscript.exe",
            "*\\wmiprvse.exe"
          ],
          "Image": [
            "*\\schtasks.exe",
            "*\\nslookup.exe",
            "*\\certutil.exe",
            "*\\bitsadmin.exe",
            "*\\mshta.exe"
          ]
        },
        "condition": "selection"
      },
      {
        "selection": {
          "EventID": 42,
          "ParentImage": [
            "*/bash",
            "*/ash"
          ],
          "Image": [
            "systemctl",
            "init"
          ]
        },
        "condition": "selection"
      }
    ],
    "fields": [
      [
        "CommandLine",
        "ParentCommandLine"
      ],
      [
        "Shell",
        "ParentShell"
      ]
    ],
    "falsepositives": [
      [
        "Administrative scripts"
      ],
      [
        "root programs"
      ]
    ],
    "level": [
      "medium",
      "high"
    ]
  }
}
```

This works on both Python 2 and 3.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is perfect.

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to keep each indicator's title/detection/fileds/etc... separate instead of putting them together?

Comment: I probably would if I knew what you are asking. Make a new question, *minimize* the input file (what I used is far bigger than necessary, but I was too lazy to cut it down for my answer, you should not be so lazy in your question), include the program you have (mine, adapted?), the JSON output you get  and the JSON output you want. You can refer to this question/my answer as background knowledge, but make the new question self contained. Tag it with [python] & [ruamel.yaml] and I'll get notified automatically.

Answer (score 1):

```
import yaml
import json

data = {}
data['indicator'] = {}
data['indicator']['detection']=[]
data['indicator']['fields']=[]
data['indicator']['falsepositives']=[]
data['indicator']['level']=[]

def parse_string(s, data):
    doc = next(yaml.safe_load_all(s))

    data['indicator']['detection'].append(doc['detection'])
    data['indicator']['fields'].append(doc['fields'])
    data['indicator']['falsepositives'].append(doc['falsepositives'])
    data['indicator']['level'].append(doc['level'])

with open(yaml_file, 'r') as yaml_in, open(json_file, 'a') as definition:
    parse_string(yaml_in.read(), data)
    json.dump(data, definition, indent=4)
```

Comment: So this is super close to what I need -- however, it doesn't write anything to my json file, and it only outputs the final indicator to my ipython console:
Out[47]: '{"indicator": {"detection": [{"selection": {"EventID": 1, "Image": ["*\\\\schtasks.exe", "*\\\\nslookup.exe", "*\\\\certutil.exe", "*\\\\bitsadmin.exe", "*\\\\mshta.exe"], "ParentImage": ["*\\\\mshta.exe", "*\\\\powershell.exe", "*\\\\cmd.exe", "*\\\\rundll32.exe", "*\\\\cscript.exe", "*\\\\wscript.exe", "*\\\\wmiprvse.exe"]}, "condition": "selection"}], "fields": [["CommandLine", "ParentCommandLine"]], "level": ["medium"], ...

Comment: @tparrott ups, indentation on last line, should work now

Comment: Actually -- this is still just outputting one of the yaml documents to the json file, is there a way to print them all?

Comment: @tparrott you can use `pprint` module to print it.